# User authentication in Keycloak using only access_token

Tags: java, authentication, grails, access-token, keycloak

First of all let me tell you guys that I am pretty new to KeyCloak authentication. In our application it is required to login into application without asking the user to enter username and password in the Keycloak login form. I was able to fetch access_token, refresh-token, session-state using the below api:

```
/auth/realms/{realms-name}/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

Now how can I use the retrieved token to make the user login directly.

```
Login flow would be:

1. We will provide a unique url to each user.
2. User will hit that url on browser.
3. App will identify the user from the unique url and retrieve his/her username and password from the db.
4. Using the username and password the app will make above api call to get the access_token and then redirect user to some url with the access_token to get it authenticated directly.
```

So, specifically I want to know that do we have any url like this, where we can pass the access-token and get the user logged in directly.

Comment: OpenID Connect and KeyCloak have been designed and implemented so that the application will never know the user's password. What you try to achieve is quite the opposite. Unless you add more information the the question my answer would be: don't implement it this way.

Comment: Thanks @ahus1 for replying :) I understand the problem and my application is working exactly the same way you have suggested. But I need a session to be created for a small group of user who can login with some unique url without redirecting them to keycloak server.

Comment: @ahus1 let me know if you want more inputs. But I really need help on this issue.